# Possible bug with the edit command while reviewing first posts

Tags: bug, review, review-audit

Today when I was reviewing first posts, I noticed that if I edit a post, then once I press the "save edit" button, I'm not taken back to the review page. Instead I'm taking to the page of the post I was editing. Twice this has caused me to not get credit for reviewing the post I had just edited. To get credit for reviewing a first post that I've just edited, I need to press my browser's back button twice to get back to the review page. I don't remember having to do this before.

Edit: Before posting the above, I decided to review another first post to see if I'm doing anything wrong. The post that came up for review was this audit: "Radius of Convergence of a complex function [closed]". The post was in need of an edit, so I clicked "edit". I got an error message that said something like "The post has been deleted and cannot be edited." The post needed an edit, but since it wouldn't let me edit it, I pressed "No Action Needed" and failed the audit. I really think there might be something wrong with the edit feature for reviewing first posts.

Comment: I've just completed an edit while reviewing a first post, and I am no longer having any problems.